Как сделать так чтобы значение свойство после вызова defineProperty не изменялось на undefined?
У меня есть код


const obj = {
  props: "Hello"
}

function useChange(obj, props, fn) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, props, {
    set(newValue) {
      fn(newValue)
    }
  })
}

useChange(obj, "props", (newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue)
})

obj.props = "Привет"
console.log(obj.props) //undefined



У меня проблема, что после вызова defineProperty значение obj.props равно не "привет", а undefined.
При это если я делаю данный вариант, то выходит ошибка:


const obj = {
  props: "Hello"
}

function useChange(obj, props, fn) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, props, {
    set(newValue) {
      fn(newValue)
      obj[props] = newValue;
    }
  })
}

useChange(obj, "props", (newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue)
})

obj.props = "Привет"
console.log(obj.props) //undefined




Uncaught
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Если знаете как сделать так чтобы после вызова defineProperty свойство не изменяло своё значение на undefined, пишите.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

ты полностью заменяешь одно свойство, на свойство с одним сеттером. Какую задачу ты хочешь решить?

Вызывая Object.defineProperty(obj, props свойство props полностью переписывается на новое. В данном случае новое свойство содержит только сеттер. Сеттер, который никуда не сохраняет новое значение. Поэтому и получить его невозможно.
В зависимости от того, как планируется применять функцию useChange варианты решения могут быть разными.
Самый просто способ - просто сохранять куда-то значение, либо в тот же объект в качестве свойства с другим именем,
либо воспользоваться замыканием.
Например:


const obj = {
  props: "Hello"
}

function useChange(obj, props, fn) {
  var propsVal = obj[props]; // используем замыкание
  Object.defineProperty(obj, props, {
    set(newValue) {
      fn(newValue)
      propsVal = newValue;
    },
    get() {
      return propsVal;
    }
  })
}

useChange(obj, "props", (newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue)
})

obj.props = "Привет"
console.log(obj.props) //undefined

const obj2 = {
  props: "Hello"
}

function useChange2(obj, props, fn) {

  var key = Symbol(props);
  obj[key] = obj[props]; // используем специальное имя
  Object.defineProperty(obj, props, {
    set(newValue) {
      fn(newValue)
      obj[key] = newValue;
    },
    get() {
      return obj[key];
    }
  })
}

useChange2(obj2, "props", (newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue)
})

obj2.props = "Привет2"
console.log(obj2.props) //undefined



